# Getting "Return" key to work with Webdriver.io

Tags: webdriver-io, geckodriver

I can't press the "Return" key in Firefox or Safari using Webdriver.io. I've been reading that `keys` will be deprecated and that `actions` are the replacement, but I haven't gotten that working either.

This is what I've tried:

```js
const { browserName } = browser.desiredCapabilities;
if (browserName === 'safari' || browserName === 'firefox') {
    browser.actions([{
        "type": "key",
        "id": "keyboard1",
        "actions": [
            {"type": "keyDown", "value": "\uE006"},
            {"type": "keyUp", "value": "\uE006"}
        ]
    }]);
    browser.actions();
} else {
    browser.keys('Return');
}
```

How do I press enter on Firefox and Safari? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `browser.keys("Enter")` and `\uE007` instead of `\uE006`?

Comment: Some details about the browser? Something that anyone can test?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve